# How do you keep your deployed Tailwind code up to date when the Figma design files are always changing?

Tags: vue.js, components, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, storybook

The problem we're facing is that many of the deployed TailwindCSS components in our Nuxt.js web application continuously need updating because of numerous design changes in Figma. How do you manage this on an ongoing basis? We've looked into tools for Component Driven design such as Bit.dev (seems pricey for startups) and the Nuxt-Storybook plugin using Tailwind is failing within the docs itself (not the best sign). Would love to hear any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe versioning the design system and versioning the TailwindCSS components?
Team collaboration and manual approach could be used or some automation could be invested. I probably would go with versioning and team communication with manual updates.

Comment: They already have versionned storybook of their components, can't do more IMO @kun

Comment: @kissu Yes, I was wondering whether the Design system was versioned? Given "application continuously needs updating because of numerous design changes in Figma"  Maybe an update strategy and when it should be executed is needed? Is fully automation wanted? There might be breaking changes that make it hard or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a tech question, more of an opinion one.

Meanwhile, you could indeed both use a Design System and Storybook. Those tools are super valuable. If your design is moving too fast, you simply need to have closer communication with your product team.

Talk with them about future changes, being able to say "no" when there are asking too much, showing them what is doable in terms of code in a short time frame and maybe not changing the design every 2 weeks could be some ways of solving this.

TLDR: not a tech issue, hence no tech tools will help you here. Human communication is enough to get over it.